# Replace recurring string in a file with a single string

Tags: python

I have a text file which has lines as below:

```
"aa aa bb aa"
"cc cc dd bb bb"
```

Wanting to remove recurring tokens to have a file like that:

```
"aa bb"
"cc dd bb"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please spend a minute reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The accepted answer may not work if you want to maintain the order.

Comment: I tried, you are right. But order is not important to me and answer meets needs of question.

Comment: I've added an answer that keeps the order, just in case you need it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In Python2.7

```
with open("datafile") as fin, open("outfile","w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        print >> fout, ' '.join(set(line.split()))
```

## In Python3.x

```
with open("datafile") as fin, open("outfile","w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        print(*(set(line.split()), file=fout)
```

Comment: Can you show pandas example?

Comment: `set` will not maintain the order. Try the input `"bb aa aa aa"`

Comment: In 3.x you can let the `print` function insert the spaces for you: `print(*(set(line.split()), file=fout)`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, Good idea. I'll use that

Answer (score 1):

In python:

```
s = "aa aa bb aa"
' '.join(set(s.split()))
```

OUTPUT:

```
'aa bb'
```

in case of the order is important try this:

```
lst = []
[lst.append(i) for i in s.split() if i not in lst]
' '.join(lst)
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to maintain the order. Try `s = "bb aa aa aa"`

Comment: @thefourtheye See the update for the order

Comment: I believe it is still wrong. It finds only unique elements. And its better not to have side-effects when you are using comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here. Although this is a bit more complicated, it will maintain the order.

```
>>> for e in s.split():
        c = set(e)
        for i in c:
            print(i)        
a
a
b
a
```

Put it in your in-file context:

```
with open('datafile') as fin, open('outfile') as fout:
    for e in s.split():
        c = set(e)
        for i in c:
            print(i, end=' ' outfile=fout)
                    #print >> fout, i #Python 2.x
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
from sets import Set
lines = ['aa aa bb aa','cc cc dd bb bb']
for l in lines:
    s = Set()
    for word in l.split():
        s.add(word)
    print ' '.join(s)
```

Comment: The `sets` module is deprecated. It has been replaced with a better implementation as the `set` and `frozenset` built-in types.